# RIPS PHP Code scanner

Tags: php, error-handling, stripslashes

> Call triggers vulnerability in function children()

```
389: ⇑ $this->children ($relativePath)
384: $relativePath = htmlspecialchars($_POST['path']); 
requires:
385: if(isset($_SESSION[Filescontroller::FC_USERNAME]) && !is_null($folderName) && !is_null($relativePath))
382: ⇓ function createfolder()
```

What does the above error mean?

Comment: Hi Code-jaff, thank you for your reply, i would really appreciate if you could provide me any link that you help me validate/sanitize data before passing, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that's because of direct passing of `$_POST['path']`. You shouldn't do that, need to properly validate/sanitize before pass. `htmlspecialchars` will just handle only one, but enormous vulnerabilities out there. - [@code-jaff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137048/rips-php-code-scanner#comment46505468_29137048)